# How to push async functions to an array without execution for a future Promise.all

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, promise

I have some async functions that make calls to a REST API and return the result.  I want to use Promise.all to call several of these functions at once and await the full result.  I understand how Promise.all works and this isn't a problem with Promise.all.  This is a problem with using Array.push to dynamically create an array of the async functions I want to call.

So here's the scenario.  A user of my app loads a page.  That page needs to retrieve data from an API.  It uses those async functions I mentioned to do that.  However, the data the page needs to retrieve is different depending on the parameters set.  So sometimes, it may need to retrieve a list of users, a specific customer, and a specific project.  Other times, it may need to get all users and all projects and no customers.

So my code looks something like this:

```
created() {
  let promiseList = []
  if (options.getCustomers) { promiseList.push(listCustomers())
  if (options.getCustomer) { promiseList.push(getCustomer(customerId)) }
  if (options.getUsers) { promiseList.push(getUsers()) }
  await Promise.all(promiseList)
}
```

So this works to some degree.  Promise.all is working just fine.  The problem is that I can't push a function to an array without it being called immediately.  Therefore, each of the functions that I'm pushing to the promiseList array gets called twice: immediately and again with Promise.all.

How can I push the async function to the array as a reference so that it's not executed immediately?

Comment: can't you just remove `()` from functions when pushing?

Comment: That won't work because sometimes I need to pass in values, for example an ID of a customer

Comment: so use `.bind`... `functionName.bind(this, customerId)`, this will bind the function with the parameter but won't call it

Comment: It doesn't work.  If I remove the () or use .bind() it passes the function as a reference but then Promise.all() doesn't work right and the returned values are Exception: TypeErrors

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put in the array the reference to the function and call then with a map when you use the Promise.all

```
created() {
  let promiseList = []
  if (options.getCustomers) { promiseList.push({ func: listCustomers })
  if (options.getCustomer) { promiseList.push({ func: getCustomer, arg: customerId}) }
  if (options.getUsers) { promiseList.push({ func: getUsers }) }
  await Promise.all(promiseList.map( (prom) => prom.func(prom.arg) ))
}
```

Comment: Perfect and easily understood! Thank you.

Comment: Why not push `() => getCustomer(customerId)` and so on, directly?

Comment: How does this generate any different result than the OP's original code?  You're still calling all the functions in the same order and still running them all in parallel.  Sure, this can work.  But, if this works, then so does the code the OP shows in their question!

Comment: @user253751 you're totally right, that's a much nicer approach

Comment: The original code executed each function twice.  The function was getting executed when it got pushed to the array.  With the example above, it does not.  Execution only happens when Promise.all calls the functions.

Comment: Funny.  I tried the approach by user253751 before even asking this question and I thought it didn't work.  Maybe I overlooked something.  Hmm....

Answer (score 6):

### You can also push the function

```
created() {
     let promiseTasks = []; // meaning name is better
     if (options.getCustomers) {
         promiseTasks.push(() => listCustomers());
     }
     if (options.getCustomer) {
         promiseTasks.push(() => getCustomer(customerId));
     }
     if (options.getUsers) {
         promiseTasks.push(() => getUsers());
     }

     await Promise.all(promiseTasks.map((func) => func()));
 }
```

> Note: I don't think it's the use case you want to use Promise.all, because its looks like all get requests, and it's better to be separated to different endpoints.

> Request option is useally can be options like: limit, sort, projection, populateQuery, preventPopulate.